# Отправить Сочетания клавиш Winapi C#

Tags: c#, winapi

Всем привет, никак не получается отправить другой программе комбинацию горячих клавиш Ctrl+0. Они посылаются по очереди, но никак не вместе, есть идеи, как это осуществить? Обязательно на Winapi с указанием дескриптора. Спасибо

Comment: Приведите ваш код, который вы пробовали.

Comment: Нужно юзать `SendInput`.